# How does Google draw street labels for its 3d maps?

Tags: c++, google-maps

I'm developing a mobile application that draws street maps in 3d. One of the issues I'm having is trying to draw street labels without any overlapping. I can get text to contour along the paths but there are a lot of places that they overlap:

[image]

Google does a pretty great job of drawing street labels without any intersections or overlapping. The 3d view in the mobile Google Maps application for Android is particularly good at demonstrating this.

The only idea I've been able to come up with is doing collision detection (with bounding spheres on each letter between close by labels). This is pretty expensive in 3d, especially with many labels on screen at once.

I was looking for some insight into how Google might be doing their street label placement or other ideas I could try that are less expensive than brute-force collision detection. The Google Maps app updates label placement in real time as you zoom and pan the display so whatever method they're using is pretty performant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it a bit I'd say. Rather than trying to collide letter by letter simplify it to a chain of lines. A name written in a straight way can be represented by one straight line. Some text inside a curved road can be approximated by using 2-3 lines at most. It doesn't have to be pixel accurate after all.

You could also build a collection of other streets "colliding" with the current one (also as positions like bridges) and then ensure your names don't overlap or get close to these positions.

Comment: In the example I've shown, the text that overlaps lies along lines that don't intersect at all. It's just that the fonts themselves are large enough to overlap each other. I think this means I'd have to either buffer the polyline that the text lies on to do the intersection tests (so compare four polylines for every label) or do a minimum distance comparison between each segment on the two lines. To me both of these methods seem more complex. But you're right that comparing characters along the same line segment is wasteful.

Comment: You mean the parkway labels? And yes, you got me wrong (my answer is a bit misleading). Simplify your text to lines or a chain of lines, then make sure they don't cross each other and also avoid them getting too close (if two of the same are nearby you could merge them anyway).